# MySQL - How do SELECT with multiple ROW output?

Tags: mysql, select

I have an `Address_table` with fields:

```
ADDRESS 
PARCELS
```

I need prepare print lables for each PARCEL with count labels "x from y"

```
ADDRESS = John, PARCELS = 3
```

How I do SELECT with this result (ADDRESS, ORDER, PARCELS):

```
John, 1, 3
John, 2, 3
John, 3, 3
```

More explain: I need to print address labels. For each address could be more labels (parcels) this is variable value. I need to know and print order of each label 1 from 5, 2 from 5, 3 from 5 etc...

```
table address:
    john
    frank
    bob

table parcels:
    3
    2
    5
```

I need this SELECT reesult:

```
john 1 3
john 2 3
john 3 3
frank 1 2
frank 2 2
bob 1 5
bob 2 5
bob 3 5
bob 4 5
bob 5 5
```

Comment: Sorry, but you tell us about 2 columns in one table. So where is the 3rd column going to come from

Comment: The column ORDER is cslculated.

Comment: It may also help if you posted the schema for these tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.ADDRESS, b.ORDER, a.PARCELS
FROM Address_table a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 1 AS `ORDER` UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) b
ON 1=1
```

Edit :
You can create additional table for number between 1 to max PARCELS
example :

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy_number_table (dummy_number INT(11) PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO Dummy_number_table VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

then you can join your address_table with dummy_number_table

```
SELECT a.ADDRESS, b.ORDER, a.PARCELS
FROM Address_table a
INNER JOIN
Dummy_number_table b
ON b.Dummy_number<=a.PARCELS
ORDER BY a.ADDRESS
```

Comment: GREAT - many thx... with dummy_table is working. simply and effective.